# Publish message to connected clients from Web API through SignalR

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, signal-processing, signalr-hub

Currently I had my server side web application to create a client to call my web API endpoint, it publish message back to web application (client) appropriately.

I have the idea, is that be possible to trigger the web API endpoint using Postman, then all connected client will receive message that this task is executing.

My endpoint

```
public class DailyPostingController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IDailyPostingService _DailyPostingService;
    private readonly ILogger<DailyPostingController> _logger;

    public DailyPostingController(IMapper mapper, 
        IDailyPostingService DailyPostingService, 
        ILogger<DailyPostingController> logger)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _DailyPostingService = DailyPostingService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Authorize(Policy = Permissions.DailyPosting.Execute)]
    [HttpPost("Execute")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<int> Execute(OperatingCentreQueryModel ocQueryModel)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Executing Daily posting for date#" 
            + ocQueryModel.ProcessDate.ToString("dd/mmm/yyy"));

        //How to trigger the hub to tell connected clients this process is started?
        var res = await _DailyPostingService.Execute(ocQueryModel);
        //How to trigger the hub to tell connected clients this process was done?
        return res;
    }
}
```

My hub

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub<INotificationHub>
{
    private readonly UsersState _usersState;
    private readonly ProcessState _processState;
    private readonly ILogger<NotificationHub> _logger;

    public NotificationHub(UsersState usersState, ProcessState processState,
        ILogger<NotificationHub> logger)
    {
        _usersState = usersState;
        _processState = processState;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.ReceiveMessage(user, message);
    }

    public async Task SendMessageToCaller(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.Caller.ReceiveMessage(user, message);
    }

    public async Task SendMessageToGroup(string user, string group, string message)
    {
        await Clients.Group(group).ReceiveMessage(user, message);
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        LogDebug($"({Context.ConnectionId}) connected to notification hub.");
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        LogDebug($"({Context.ConnectionId}) disconnected to notification hub.");
        _usersState.RemoveConnectionId(Context.ConnectionId,
            async (user) =>
            {
                await RemoveUser(user);
                await RemoveUserProcess(user);
            });

        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }

    private void LogDebug(string msg)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("*** " + msg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs describe how to do this https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

###### You can send SignalR messages from other places in your app using the IHubContext service. You simply inject it where you need to use it.

To address your issue I would add a new method to INotificationHub:

```
public interface INotificationHub
{
    Task ExcecutingDailyPost(string action);
}
```

Inject your strongly typed hub context wherever you need to use hub functionality.

Your endpoint could then look like this:

```
public class DailyPostingController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IDailyPostingService _DailyPostingService;
    private readonly ILogger<DailyPostingController> _logger;
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub, INotificationHub> _hubContext;

    public DailyPostingController(IMapper mapper, 
        IDailyPostingService DailyPostingService, 
        ILogger<DailyPostingController> logger,
        IHubContext<NotificationHub, INotificationHub> hubContext)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _DailyPostingService = DailyPostingService;
        _logger = logger;
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    [Authorize(Policy = Permissions.DailyPosting.Execute)]
    [HttpPost("Execute")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<int> Execute(OperatingCentreQueryModel ocQueryModel)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Executing Daily posting for date#" 
            + ocQueryModel.ProcessDate.ToString("dd/mmm/yyy"));
        
        // Notify your clients that the process has started
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.ExcecutingDailyPost("START");

        var res = await _DailyPostingService.Execute(ocQueryModel);

        // Notify your clients that the process has ended
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.ExcecutingDailyPost("END");
        return res;
    }
}
```

Then on the client side you need to listen on the "ExcecutingDailyPost" channel and depending on the action, do what you would like.